# Can anyone help me with designing a logic circuit from a truth table

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Im having trouble with designing a circuit with logic gates that represents this truth table:

A B C X

0 0 0 0

0 0 1 1

0 1 0 1

0 1 1 1

1 0 0 1

1 0 1 1

1 1 0 1

1 1 1 0

We can use NOT gates, AND(2inputs), OR(2inputs).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework, what have you tried so far? Karnaugh map?

Comment: Do take Tyler's question serious: on SE-EE homework question without prior effort are closed. With good reasons.

Comment: Well, it is homework, but im really having a hard time figuring this out, ill look into Karnaugh maps tho!

Comment: You can do it with 3 NOT, 3AND, 2 OR. That should help you once you have you Kmap sorted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's obviously a homework, but it was fun to solve it. Here you go: https://simulator.io/board/Jd6JyfDkYb/2

X is true as soon as one of the three ANDs are true:

- !A & C
- B & !C
- A & !B